# Tool to view video/audio file information

Tags: windows, video, audio, metadata

What is the best tool to obtain the media/codec details of any video/audio file?

I use Windows, but feel free to suggest for your favorite OS too.

Comment: related: http://superuser.com/questions/18001/which-codec-inside-mkv-file

Comment: your site is rotting. Found an outdated answer[1] that was closed as a duplicate of this outdated answer which was closed as off topic because you mods have to no power in life to you enjoy ego trips here. Useless, thanks SuperUsers. You're super.

1: https://superuser.com/questions/404489/how-do-i-determine-the-file-type-of-a-video-file

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[MediaInfo](http://mediainfo.sourceforge.net/en)

```
What information can I get from MediaInfo?

General: title, author, director, album, track number, date, duration...
Video: codec, aspect, fps, bitrate...
Audio: codec, sample rate, channels, language, bitrate...
Text: language of subtitle
Chapters: number of chapters, list of chapters

What format (container) does MediaInfo support?

Video: MKV, OGM, AVI, DivX, WMV, QuickTime, Real, MPEG-1, MPEG-2, MPEG-4, DVD (VOB)...
(Codecs: DivX, XviD, MSMPEG4, ASP, H.264, AVC...)
Audio: OGG, MP3, WAV, RA, AC3, DTS, AAC, M4A, AU, AIFF...
Subtitles: SRT, SSA, ASS, SAMI...
```

Answer (score 15):

I used to have this tool called [**GSpot270a**](http://www.headbands.com/gspot/v26x/index.htm),
there is a [quick start here](http://www.headbands.com/gspot/v26x/quick_start.html).

And a [comparison of some tools here](http://www.streamingmedia.com/article.asp?id=10433).

1. QuickTime Pro (commercial); [Lillipot](http://www.qtbridge.com/lillipot/lillipot.html)

   - Intel Semaphore (commercial)
   - [**GSpot**](http://gspot.headbands.com)
   - [**MediaInfo**](http://mediainfo.sourceforge.net/en) (Sourceforge)
   - [**wmsnoop**](http://www.sliq.com/default.asp?view=wmsnoop)

---

There is this blog post
[**View and Analyze Your Media Codec Information (Video/Audio) With MediaInfo**](http://www.tmsnetwork.org/blog/view-and-analyze-your-media-codec-information-videoaudio-mediainfo)
which does not open at this time... don't know why, but it has the lines,

> **MediaInfo** can be considered as the alternative tool for **GSpot** Codec Information Appliance. MediaInfo is being actively developed.

I can see GSpot is not actively developed.

Comment: Another interesting one I tested this week "playtime" http://skwire.dcmembers.com/wb/pages/software/playtime.php Main purpose is to give you total times, but it integrated the media info library in a more portable package, and a very nice viewing interface. It does not have the capability to display all the really deep header info like Bpov, but all the stuff most users would want to see is there. 2things in small clean package.