# how do I determine the file type of a video file

Tags: video, file-extension

Sometimes I get the url of a video embedded in a webpage and download it, just to find the file has no extension name.

I can play the video with a player, so it must be legal.

How do I determine the extension name of the video file in such circumstance?

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: @boehj Mac OS X

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Mediainfo](http://mediainfo.sourceforge.net/en), it is the best tool out there for this job.

Comment: Didn't work for me - the file I can't play is just showing as "350MiB container" in MediaInfo, no video info at all

Comment: same with me unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't already, open up a folder and go to Tools -> Folder Options -> View -> and deselect 'Hide extensions for known file types'

If you are downloading from YouTube, the format is going to be a .flv (flash video) unless your downloader converts it.

If all else fails, just click on the webpage, view the source, and find out where the video was embedded on the page and find the format. If you are getting them all from the same site, they are more than likely all going to have the same format.

These are just a few things I could think of, I hope they might possibly help you.

Answer (score 0):

Or [Gspot](http://www.headbands.com/gspot/index.htm). Reviews HERE. It allows you to see what container, internal codec etc that your video is using.

Comment: Development stopped in 2007 ;p