# Can I add MKV support to Windows Media Player in Windows 8 without installing anything?

Tags: windows-8, windows-media-player, codec, matroska, video-codecs

Is it possible for me to just copy a codec file into a directory without having to install some janky codec pack filled with all kinds of nonsense? I just want to be able to play MKV files without running some type of installation executable.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using a bloated and non-native portable application, I'd suggest using [MPC-HC Lite](http://nightly.mpc-hc.org/lite/). The project is updated every 2 days and is always available as an installer or a .zip package (portable). And to support the MKV container and it's video stream, you only need [LAV Filters](http://forum.doom9.org/showthread.php?t=156191).
The lite version comes with no codecs. Cleanest player there is.
Everything is portable.

Answer (score 2):

[MKV is a container](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matroska), not an encoding format.  Since it could be many different encoding formats inside the MKV, that's usually why people (in general) suggest installing a CODEC pack to get MKV support.

Perhaps check out this related SU question: [which codec inside mkv file?](https://superuser.com/questions/18001/which-codec-inside-mkv-file)..

Answer (score 1):

this is not possible without installing a correct codec. You can use a portable media player like this one:

http://portableapps.com/de/apps/music_video/vlc_portable

if you don't want to install anything.